# jquery each a href should so something

Tags: jquery

hi Everyone i wonder if there any solution to select a href to do something without repeating or giving any classes or id in a href it self.
for example like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="google.com">google</a><li>
  <li><a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a><li>
  <li><a href="facebook.com">facebook</a><li>
</ul>
```

and in jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('li a').on('click', function(){
    console.log('open google.com');
    console.log('open yahoo.com');
    console.log('open facebook.com');
  });
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make the links proper links?

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, and becouse i've tried to figured out each a href should do something latter on and not just only open up the link. :(

Comment: What is it you want to do that you are not already doing in your example?

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost, thanks for your answer and your question. i tried to figured out using jquery that in every a href letter on has own a function behind that, and each onclick link should do there own function. and not only open up the link. sorry the unclear question from me.

Answer (score 1):

In your quoted event handler, you can access the `href` of the clicked element like this:

```
console.log($(this).attr("href"));
```

If the hrefs were in a proper form (they aren't in the question), you could use:

```
console.log(this.href);
```

to get the fully-resolved version.

In either case, to prevent the browser trying to follow the link, use `e.preventDefault()` or just `return false` from the function (which both prevents the dfeault and stops propagation).

**Live Example:**

```js
$(function(){
  $('li a').on('click', function() {
    snippet.log($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="google.com">google</a><li>
  <li><a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a><li>
  <li><a href="facebook.com">facebook</a><li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Or with the links in proper form:

```js
$(function(){
  $('li a').on('click', function() {
    snippet.log(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://google.com">google</a><li>
  <li><a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</a><li>
  <li><a href="http://facebook.com">facebook</a><li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```